# if 2 processes have same exection time in presumptive STF,how do we decide which to pick?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

Image of table:

[image: table]

Textual representation

| process | arrival time | execution time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 3 |
| b | 2 | 2 |
| c | 2 | 2 |
| d | 5 | 5 |
| e | 8 | 1 |

From the table if 2 processes have same exection time in presumptive STF,how do we decide which to pick.and solution